# Python: updating a large dictionary using another large dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to update some values of a large dictionary using values from another dictionary where they have similar keys (the same date but in a different format). The process I'm currently using is too slow and I want to reduce the bottleneck.

This is my current solution (it writes the updated dict to a file):

```
from dateutil import parser
File = open(r'E:Test1.txt','w')

b = {'1946-1-1':0,..........,'2012-12-31':5}
d = {'1952-12-12':5,........,'1994-7-2':10}

for key1, val1 in b.items():
    DateK1 = parser.parse(key1)
    Value = val1
    for key2, val2 in d.items():
        DateK2 = parser.parse(key2)
        if DateK1 == DateK2:
            d[key2] = Value        

Order= sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])

for item in Order:
    File.write('%s,%s\n' % item)
File.close()
```

Comment: why do you do a `for` on `d`? that defeats the whole purpose of hash. do a `print dir({})` in python shell, understand what every method does. pls try something and post your work.

Comment: @ tuxuday: I was trying to use dateutil parser in d and b, but it was not right. see below how Hayden answer helped, he transformed d and b to include the parser (usind "for" inside), then updated the dict d.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a pretty crappy question and it's not even clear from the accepted answer how the OP wanted the merge to happen.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use the [`update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method to merge dictionaries:

```
b.update(d)
```

.

At the moment you are iterating over `d` for every key in `b`... which is slow. You can get around this by setting up two dictionaries which will have matching keys (and equal dates will hash the same - *perhaps the cool thing to note here is that datetime objects hash*):

```
b1 = dict( (parser.parse(k),v) for k,v for b.iteritems() )
d1 = dict( (parser.parse(k),v) for k,v for d.iteritems() )

d1.update(b1) # update d1 with the values from b1
```

#### Edit:

I've just realised that you're not *quite* doing an update, since only those shared values are being updated, so instead (again by just iterating once):

```
for k_d1 in d1:
    if k_d1 in b1:
        d1[k_d1] = b1[k_d1]
```

Comment: So how do I avoid the iteration..since I have to parse the key so that is read a "date"...some keys might be same date in both dicts but I appear in slighty different format: for example "1946-1-1" and "1946-01-1" or "1946-01-01"

Comment: @EricGentil Ah ok, I have updated with them parsed, it gets them all in the same format this way, is this solution good for you? (This should work, because datetimes are hashable.)

Comment: @EricGentil Added edit, since you are only updating those which are already in d (my mistake!)

Comment: @hyden: your idea works..but I think the second "for" should be "in" like this  b1 = dict( (parser.parse(k),v) for k,v in b.iteritems()) ..right?

Comment: Since this answer is accepted, I guess the two dictionaries' keys really *are* the same, not in different formats?

Comment: @wberry: I was thinking once you put the date parser in front of keys..then even if they are in different format but same date they are considered same during update. Right?..

Comment: @EricGentil That's the point of [`parser()`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2)...

Comment: @ hayden: I realized your answer might not be correct: you have also to iterate b1. The code I posted gave me the right answer but it is extremely slow (after a couple hours). wberry suggestion of just using d.iteritems instead of d.items() (same for b) in my usual code might save me sometime..but I have to chech since the code is still running (after a dozen minutes)

Comment: @ hayden:the script is fast, but i am not d1 is not getting updates.  so when you say " for k_d1 in d1.iteritems"  don't you think it checks both keys and values? then when it even finds similar values in both dictionaries it updates d1?

Answer (score 3):

Suggested changes:

1. Use `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`.  The way you have it, a list of pairs is created in memory and iterated over, which is wasteful.
2. You said that the date format is different between `b` and `d`.  I'm guessing the month and day are switched?  If so, you can still make big savings by computing what the `d` key would be and then checking membership.

Code with changes:

```
def switch_month_day(datestr):
  fields = datestr.split("-")
  return "%s-%s-%s" % (fields[0], fields[2], fields[1])

for key, val in b.iteritems():
  DateK = switch_month_day(key)
  if DateK in d:
    d[DateK] = val
```

Comment: you brought up a good point.. I had not noticed that the parser might not consider year_month_day order... I had accepted the answer before checking..but let me go through and check the which one give me the right answer!

Comment: Edited my answer to say `switch_month_day(key)` and not use the `parser` function any more, based on format of dict keys in the question.

Comment: The dateutil parser is very useful because if for some reason there is data point with a date having space or instead of '-' , it can read date and time in any format and harmonise them to look similar which helped when sorting. So do you think the parser slowed down the code?

Comment: Probably not a significant slowdown.  Using `iteritems` and not doing a quadratic-time iteration over both dictionaries would most likely far outweigh that.  I was just considering how to switch month and day, which your question does not make perfectly clear whether that's necessary or not.